# How can I implement Declaration to bouncy ball?

Tags: java, android, acceleration

i am trying to implement Deceleration on the bouncy ball. i am able to move the ball up and down but i wanted to add Declaration so when i drop the ball from height it jumps then strike the ground bounce once again and slowly slowly its speed decreases and stop at the end.

**Here is My code**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{
private Context mContext;
int x = -1;
int y = -1;
private int xVelocity = 0;
private int yVelocity = 25;
private Handler h;
private final int FRAME_RATE = 20;


public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
    super(context, attrs);  
    mContext = context;  
    h = new Handler();
} 

private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        invalidate(); 
    }
};

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  

    BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
    if (x<0 && y <0) {
        x = this.getWidth()/2;
        y = this.getHeight()/2;
    } else {
        x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;
        if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
        }
        if ((y > this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) || (y < 0)) {
            yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
        }
    }
    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

    h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);


}
```

Hope Anyone Can Help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Acceleration is just a change in velocity over time...

Comment: yeah, i know but i cannot understand how can i hit the ground with each time so that when my ball comes back its speed decreases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceleration is to velocity as velocity is to position. You just need to do what you're doing with your position to your velocity.

The simplest solution is to add

```
yVelocity += yAccel;
```

to the top of onDraw where yAccel is a int that you want added to the yVelocity every tick. Based on your velocity values

```
private int yAccel = -2;
```

might be appropriate.

edit: You should also add checks to ensure the ball does not go into the ground. I added these in the blocks that reverse the velocity, the following code works for me. If it don't work for you, there might be something wrong with another part of your project.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimatedView extends ImageView {
    private Context mContext;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    private int xVelocity = 0;
    private int yVelocity = 25;
    private int yAccel = 2;
    private Handler h;
    private final int FRAME_RATE = 20;

    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        h = new Handler();
    }

    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate();
        }
    };



    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        yVelocity += yAccel;

        BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.cakes);
        if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
            x = this.getWidth() / 2;
            y = this.getHeight() / 2;
        } else {
            x += xVelocity;
            y += yVelocity;
            if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                xVelocity = xVelocity * -1;
                x = Math.min(this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth(), x);
                x = Math.max(0, x);
            }
            if ((y > this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight())
                    || (y < 0)) {
                yVelocity = (int)(yVelocity * -0.8f);

                y = Math.min(this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight(), y);
                y = Math.max(0, y);
            }
        }
        c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);

        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i am not able to implement the decrease speed it start increasing speed without touching ground and lastly it hanged.

Comment: I added the full code for the class to the answer. It worked fine when I tested it.

Comment: now it hitting the ground with some height but it's speed is not decreasing(Deceleration) with each bounce.

Comment: Ah. I missed that requirement, sorry.

You can bleed off speed during the bounce by changing
    `yVelocity = yVelocity * -1;`
to
    `yVelocity = (int)(yVelocity * -0.8f);`

I'll update the post accordingly.

Comment: Wow!!great it work for me.Now i am trying to bounce the ball with my finger and ball move in any direction can you guide me how can i proceed.